# Use of " and ' in multi-paragraph quotes

Tags: quotation-marks

I was taught that I should use " at the start of a quote and if it carries on in subsequent paragraphs, I should put ' at the end of the first paragraph, then start the second paragraph with ' and close again with ' and so on, until the final paragraph which I close with ' ".  I cannot see any reference to this style.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen the style of quoting you mention in use.

[Jesse Game-Brown's site](http://jesse.istheguy.com/WebHelp/Quotation_Marks/Quotation_Marks_Multi-paragraph_Quotes.htm) states:

> The AP Stylebook and The New York Times Manual of Style and Usage
>   suggest beginning every paragraph of a multi-paragraph quote with
>   quotation marks, but saving the concluding quotation marks for the end
>   of the quotation.

It offers this as passage as an example:

> “What we, the Tree Warriors, are, despite what we’ve heard, is nothing
>   short of miraculous. Only the most insecure of politicians would dare
>   to attack a group with our integrity and commitment to justice and
>   happiness for all. We are not to be shaken by such words of weakness.
>
> “My assistant, Belinda, tells me that our Tree Warriors association
>   ranks highest among all the associations. Belinda is quite the
>   researcher. Let’s have a round of applause for Belinda.”

This style is what I most commonly see used with multi-paragraph quotes.

Comment: @yates You're welcome, please mark the answer as _accepted_.

Comment: How do I mark as accepted?  I am new to the site.

Comment: Here you go: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

[Block quotes](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_formatting_quotations.html) are usually the clearest way to indicate longer quotations. I've never seen the format you reference.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I agree that block quotation format is another option.